# @CreationTimestamp is not available with Instant Variable

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to use `@CreationTimestamp` for an instance variable of [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) type.

I am using `hibernate.version 5.2.10` and imported `import org.hibernate.annotations.*;` 
but still showing **No Default Proposals**.

Here is my code

```
import java.time.Instant;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class AbstractEntity {

        @Id
        @Column(nullable=false,updatable=false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        protected Long id;

        @CreationTimestamp
        protected Instant created;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Instant getCreated() {
            return created;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how it worked now
here is what I did

1. Used [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310)
2. and used **@EntityScan** in my main class

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)` annotation on the class.